# go - Render html/template with inheritance

Tags: html, inheritance, go, render, template-engine

I have two html templates, with `index.html` extending `base.html`

`base.html` is like this:

```
{{ define "base" }}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charget="utf-8">
    <title>{{ template "title" . }}</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    {{ template "index" . }}
</body>
</html>
{{ end }}
```

And `index.html`:

```
{{ define "title" }}Homepage{{ end }}
{{ define "index" }}
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left">
                <img src="../public/images/img_landing_page_mac.png">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <h2 style="font-size: 33px; letter-spacing: 5px">Organize <br>Modern Knowledge<br> for Mankind</h2>
                <p style="font-size: 20px;margin-top: 35px;letter-spacing: 4px">Consume, Colect and Revisit <br>Knowledge at Your Fingertips</p>
                <a href="#" style="margin-top: 80px;display: inline-block;margin-left: -17px"><img src="../public/images/btn_get_chrome.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ end }}
```

It should render when requesting path on browser with a callback handler:

```
func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
    files:=[]string{"base","index"}
    util.RenderTemplate(w,nil,files...)
}
```

`RenderTemplate` is a wrapper function to render

```
func RenderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter,data interface{},tmpl... string){
    cwd,_:=os.Getwd()
    files:=make([]string, len(tmpl))
    for i,file:=range tmpl{
        files[i]=filepath.Join(cwd,"./view/"+file+".html")
    }
    t,err:=template.ParseFiles(files...)
    if err!=nil{
        http.Error(w,err.Error(),http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    templates:=template.Must(t,err)
    err=templates.Execute(w,data)
    if err!=nil {
        http.Error(w,err.Error(),http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

After I start server, I request that path on browser, but nothing is rendered at all. What am I missing? It seems that no inheritance is comprehended here

I follow this tutorial, trying to render templates with inheritance / extension:

https://elithrar.github.io/article/approximating-html-template-inheritance/

Comment: What status code is being returned? 200? 500?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`define`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Nested_template_definitions) action doesn't execute template, only `template` and `block` actions do. Most probably you just want to remove `define` from your base template (first and last lines) and it will work as expected.

Or you can use `Template.ExecuteTemplate` function instead of `Template.Execute`. It accepts name of the template:
    err = templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", data)

Or if you are using Go1.6 or newer you can try [`block`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) action instead of `define`.

On the side note, please, consider using [gofmt](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#formatting).